# Does /me/likes/page_id require user_likes permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Previously, Facebook app's could check if a user liked a given page (for fan-gating) by calling the following Graph API method with no special permissions other than basic authentication:

```
/me/likes/page_id
```

This would return a `data` property with the page's details if the user has liked it previously, or an empty array when the user hasn't liked the page.

Seems that this has recently stopped working. Instead, the only way to get this information is, if the `user_likes` permission had been granted prior.

The same problem is encountered when using

```
/page_id/members/user_id
```

Is there any information on what's causing this new behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but the 2nd call you list would imply that the current user had rights to veiw your page's members list. Really the list of people who like a page should be restricted to the page owner although Facebook does show you who of your friends likes the page as well.

As for user liking the page, I've been searching today for the same and this answer seemed to be the best so far:

[StackOverflow: Check if user likes page via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566575/check-if-user-likes-page-via-graph-api)