# Check if an users likes a page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if user likes page via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566575/check-if-user-likes-page-via-graph-api)

I know this probably has been asked already a few time, however, since I'm a newbie of the new Facebook SDK, I'm having some difficulties.

Basically, what I want to do is very simple. I've got a whole web page that I want to show only if an user likes my Facebook page. Otherwise, he gets asked to like the page first.

I would like to know what differences there are between the Javascript or PHP methods, and if it's possible to achieve this only if the user gives the authorization to my Facebook application first.

I don't think to obtain something so simple should be that difficult, so I would love if someone could post me an easy-to start, updated guide or some example code.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this. However, if someone is able to add something more to get the things more clear would be very appreciated.

Comment: Checked, however it doesn't says much

Answer (score 0):

Outside of Facebook (canvas/page tab app) you can only get the info whether a user likes your page or not by having him connect to an app first, and have that app ask for permission to read his likes.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

(But this might be a little much to ask, if your app offers nothing else to the user – I would not allow any app to do that if it does not offer me some more benefits for using it; I’d rather turn away from your site completely if you want me to like content before I have even been able to see it.)